# Validate contents under optional key in map with Taoensso Truss

Tags: clojure

```
(require '[taoensso.truss :as truss])
```

Say that we have a map describing i circle. A circle always has a center, but can be described either through a diameter or a radius:

```
{:center [1, 2] :diameter 10}
{:center [1, 2] :radius   5}
```

Both the above circles describe the same circle.

So say we have a function that expects a circle map as its input, how can we best assert this with truss? The start of the code could look like:

```
(defn circle-tosser
  [circle-map]
  (truss/have map? circle-map)
  (truss/have number? :in (:center circle-map))
  (str "Tossing " circle-map))

(circle-tosser {:center [1, 2] :radius 5})
;; => "Tossing {:center [1 2], :radius 5}"
```

The problem is of course that we can't just straight up assert that the values of these keys have certine properties, since they don't neccicerily exist. For example the below declaration would require both keys to be present at the same time:

```
(defn circle-tosser
  [circle-map]
  (truss/have map? circle-map)
  (truss/have number? :in (:center circle-map))
  (truss/have number? (:diameter circle-map))
  (truss/have number? (:radius   circle-map))
  (str "Tossing " circle-map))

(circle-tosser {:center [1, 2] :diameter 10}) ; Unhandled Exception
(circle-tosser {:center [1, 2] :diameter 10 :radius 5})
;; => "Tossing {:center [1 2], :diameter 10, :radius 5}"
```

You could then start writing things like

```
(defn circle-tosser
  [circle-map]
  (truss/have map? circle-map)
  (truss/have number? :in (:center circle-map))
  (when (contains? circle-map :diameter)
    (truss/have number? (:diameter circle-map)))
  (when (contains? circle-map :radius)
    (truss/have number? (:radius   circle-map)))
  (str "Tossing " circle-map))

(circle-tosser {:center [1, 2] :diameter 10})
;; => "Tossing {:center [1 2], :diameter 10}"
```

but that starts becoming overly verbose and impossible to read, which is unfortunate since providing accesible documentation (in the form of code), is part of truss's purpose.

Perhaps you can come up with a much improved way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to define a function to hide away the repeated code, like

```
(defn opt-key
  [key predicate data]
  (when (contains? data key)
    (truss/have predicate (get data key))))


(defn circle-tosser
  [circle-map]
  (truss/have map? circle-map)
  (truss/have number? :in (:center circle-map))
  (opt-key :diameter number? circle-map)
  (opt-key :radius   number? circle-map)
  (str "Tossing " circle-map))

(circle-tosser {:center [1, 2] :diameter 10})
;; => "Tossing {:center [1 2], :diameter 10}"
```

Left of course, for this example, is to introduce a concept of mutual exclusivity. But then it's probably better to normalize the data as Alan Thompson suggests.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to solve your problem.

(1) Always generate circles with `radius` and never `diameter`

(2) If you can't do (1), every reference to a circle will need to be wrapped in a conversion function like the following:

```
(defn normalize [c]
  (if (contains? c :diameter)
    (-> c
      (assoc :radius (/ (:diameter c) 2))
      (dissoc :diameter))
    c))
```

and your code will look like

```
(defn circle-tosser
  [circle-map]
  (let [c (normalize circle-map) ]
    (truss/have map? c)
    (truss/have number? :in (:center c))
    (str "Tossing " c)))
```

I always prefer solution (1), but sometimes (2) cannot be avoided.

Comment: I see how your points are valid to the example of circles. Perhaps I did wrong by using a non-real-world example. Think instead that the example is "We have a configuration map which has many different optional keys, we want to validate the values of these", like the leiningen project.clj. Do you think I should make a new post with that example instead?